# Wise: How to install files into a path specified in the registry

Tags: windows-installer, wise

I'm writing a .msi using Wise Installer Editor and I want to copy all my files into a directory specified in a registry key.

How can I specify this in Wise?

Thanks in advance,

Ernesto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following:

1. Assume that on the destination computer you have following registry key: "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Custom" and some value named "directory" which is set to "C:\program files\MyDestinationDirectory"
2. in the Editor you select: Target System\System Search where you add new Registry Search Type:

   - for Property select: INSTALLDIR (main installation directory)
   - for Operation select: Read directory name from registry
   - Root and Key set to be equal to above registry key ("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Custom")
   - for value name select: "directory"

So when installation starts, destination directory will be equal to those defined in the registry.

But there is a catch: the directory must exist; "C:\program files\MyDestinationDirectory" needs to be a valid path.

Anyway, hope this helps a bit:)